# What should we do with users that never reply

Tags: discussion, users

I have answered many questions and the question asker does not reply or mark as answered. These questions are bad for the site and will make it have more unanswered questions.

Is there anything we could do about this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually the correct process would be to post a close flag under "unclear what you're asking". If you need a reply to answer the question this is correct anyway, if not, then others users may upvote your answer (any upvoted answer stops the question being marked as unanswered).

Comment: Most of these are unanswered. I try to answer them by adding a comment asking for some information but they never reply. This will cause the number of unanswered questions to increase